# Multi-dimensional array in VBA for Microsoft Word on Mac

Tags: vba, macos, replace, ms-word

I'm working on a macro to loop through a series of strings (`a1, a2, a3`) and replace them with a series of corresponding values (`b1, b2, b3`). I've created an array to store the strings to match:

```
Dim search_strings(1 To 2) As String
search_strings(1) = "match1"
search_strings(2) = "match2"
```

I can loop through this array with a `For Each` loop. But I can't figure out how to store and reference the corresponding replacement text. I know that I need some sort of key/value pair. I've tried using a dictionary, like this:

```
Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
dict.Add "match", "replace"
```

But for that to work, I need to reference Microsoft Scripting Runtime, which isn't available on Mac OS X. (Currently, I get this error: `Compile error: User-defined type not defined`.)

Is there another way?

Here's the full code:

```
Sub MyMacro()
    ' Initialize variables
    Dim search_strings(1 To 2) As String
    Dim this_search_string As Variant
    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim Reply As Integer
    ' Define strings to match
    search_strings(1) = "match1"
    search_strings(2) = "match2"
    ' Run a search for each string in the array of strings to match
    For Each this_search_string In search_strings
        ' Define the search range to be the whole document
        Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Content
        ' Set the Find parameters
        myRange.Find.ClearFormatting
        myRange.Find.MatchWildcards = True
        ' Loop through each match in the document
        Dim cached As Long
        cached = myRange.End
        Do While myRange.Find.Execute(this_search_string)
            myRange.Select
            ' Prompt the user to replace the match
            Reply = MsgBox("Replace '" & myRange.Find.Text & "'?", vbYesNoCancel)
            If Reply = 6 Then ' "Yes" clicked
                myRange.Text = "replacement"
            ElseIf Reply = 2 Then ' "Cancel" clicked
                Exit Do
            End If
            myRange.Start = myRange.Start + Len(myRange.Find.Text)
            myRange.End = cached
        Loop
    Next this_search_string
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be completely off and I may look like a fool but have you tried using a two dimensional array so you can store the values with their replacements in the two dimensional array. Then you can loop through to get the replacement values. That is just an idea I had, it could be way off.

```
Sub MyMacro()
    ' Initialize variables
    Dim search_strings(1 To 2, 1 to 2) As String
    Dim this_search_string As Variant
    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim Reply As Integer
    ' Define strings to match
    search_strings(1, 1) = "match1"
    search_strings(2, 1) = "match2"
    search_strings(1, 2) = "result"
    search_strings(2, 2) = "result"
    ' Run a search for each string in the array of strings to match
    For Each this_search_string In search_strings
        ' Define the search range to be the whole document
        Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Content
        ' Set the Find parameters
        myRange.Find.ClearFormatting
        myRange.Find.MatchWildcards = True
        ' Loop through each match in the document
        Dim cached As Long
        cached = myRange.End
        Do While myRange.Find.Execute(this_search_string)
            myRange.Select
            ' Prompt the user to replace the match
            Reply = MsgBox("Replace '" & myRange.Find.Text & "'?", vbYesNoCancel)
            If Reply = 6 Then ' "Yes" clicked
                myRange.Text = search_strings(1, 2)
            ElseIf Reply = 2 Then ' "Cancel" clicked
                Exit Do
            End If
            myRange.Start = myRange.Start + Len(myRange.Find.Text)
            myRange.End = cached
        Loop
    Next this_search_string
End Sub
```

Im really not sure if this is what you are looking for so I apologize if I am wasting your time.

Comment: I just edited my previous answer to contain sample code.

Comment: The two-dimensional array example is all I need. I can work out the rest.